# Capybara: Find or page.have_* don't work (ElementNotFound)

Tags: testing, capybara

Methods '*page.have_**' or '*find*' do not work in any way.

I double checked and the code is all right.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Control the character encoding of the file, it may be corrupted or wrong.

Try to recreate the view file, it can help.